# how can i make some datasets in r?

Tags: r, dataset, simulation

I'm studying imbalanced learning problems. 'Imbalanced' means that data set exhibits an unequal distribution between its classes, for example you gave a binary classification problem with 1000 examples. A total of 900 examples are labeled with class-0 and the others 100 examples are labeled with class-1.

Most of classification algorithms do not consider the underlying distribution of the datasets, so they didn't handle this 'imbalanced learning problems'. Because if they classify all examples to class-0, then they have 90% accuracy.

One of the leading problems in class imbalance classification is class overlapping occurrences in the datasets. Also the imbalance within a single class might aggravate the problems.(Classification with class imbalance problem: A review, Aida Ali, Siti Mariyam Shamsuddin, and Anca L.Ralescu, ISSN 2074-8523)

So I want to simulate these problems like 1) comparing some methods when datasets have different overlapping degrees, 2) comparing some methods when dataset heve within class imbalance.
[datasets have overlapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdNS3.jpg)

[datasets have within class imbalance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xSRR.jpg)

So I have to make dataset in r, I don't know how to generate these datasets.
I just make some independent variables

```
set.seed(3)
x1    <- rnorm(n)           # normal dist
x3    <- rexp(n)            # exponential dist
x5    <- rpois(n,lambda=3)  # poisson dist
error <- rnorm(n)           # error term
```

And now I have to make class variable Y that has relation with these X's. I think I can adjust overlapping ratio by coefficient of X's.

```
IR  <- 90 # IR means imbalanced ratio  'IR=# of class0/# of class1'
eta <- -200*x1 + 0.5*sin(x3) + 300*x5^3 + error
Y   <- as.factor( ifelse( eta > quantile( eta, IR/(IR+1) ), 1, 0) )
```

But Actually I don't know my code is correct. Also I wonder how can i make within class imbalance dataset.
Could you help me? How can I make this datasets?

Comment: You really only need to call `set.seed` once to make your data reproducible.

Comment: @xxfelixxx  thanks i revised about that.

Comment: Take a look at this post. Has a great 3 class dataset that the person creates with weights 1:49:50 (50:2450:2500 actually) https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157714/r-package-for-weighted-random-forest-classwt-option

Comment: Instead of `ifelse` it's better `as.integer(eta > quantile( eta, IR/(IR+1))`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use built-in function [`twoClassSim`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caret/versions/6.0-24/topics/twoClassSim) from *caret* package.

```
library(caret)
set.seed(123)
data <- twoClassSim(
  1000,
  intercept = -16.5,
  linearVars = 15,
  noiseVars = 5
)
table(data$Class)

Class1 Class2 
   899    101
```